# Does the pandamonium card counter blinding light's effects?

Tags: unstable-unicorns

Does the pandamonium card counter blinding light's effects? [image: narwhal torpedo, blinding light, and pandamonium cards]

Answer (score 3):

By explicit card text, yes. Blinding Light only affects Unicorns

> ... of your Unicorn cards...

and Pandamonium explicitly counters exactly that.

> All of your Unicorns are considered Pandas. Cards that affect Unicorns do not affect your Pandas.